# Super simple templating tool

Tags: templates, template-engine

I've often wanted a simple tool that could take text templates, then output a user friendly page/view that asks the user for each unique variable. The important bit is that creating the templates are non-programmer friendly, and that the interactive template filler is cross-platform friendly. It is for generating text configurations for embedded equipment.

Templates would look like

> ```
> Hello $firstname
> Your favorite color is $favoritecolor
> I have now been introduced to $firstname who likes $favoritecolor
> ```

I *know in my bones* that this must exist, but I just can't seem to craft the right keywords for a search engine to avail me.

Comment: which language are you using? Java? JavaScript? C#?

Comment: I'll take just about any language in which a useful package exists. I could make something from scratch (it's not rocket science), but I don't think I'm the first or even in the first thousand to have this problem.

Comment: Languages that wouldn't be taxing though; C, [C], Python, Perl, Shell. Anything else wouldn't bother me as long as it's not an esoteric language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is TemplateFx (https://templatefx.org), which as the title asks for, is a simple Templating tool which we use at work for various tasks. It is mostly used to generate router configs based on our standard site templates. However, as the Op also mentions a library it might not be what they are after.

**2021 UPDATE** If you want an open source and non proprietary solution which uses Jinja2 templating which is commonly used with Ansible and other tools then I also wrote JinjaFx which is written in Python and has a web frontend at https://jinjafx.io

Comment: Even though this isn't spot on, and even though it is closed source and proprietary, it will do. Thank you kindly :-)

Comment: STILL use it from time to time. The author is a great guy!